# как заменить border outline-ом но с радиусом? (либо убрать смещение блоков из-за толщины border)

Tags: css

Проблема в следующем, `border` увеличивает размер блока на свою толщину. Мне необходимо сделать так, что при нажатии на элемент толщина `border` не сдвигала следующие за ним блоки, т.е. чтобы "не было прыжков" блоков и они оставались не подвижными, я понимаю, что это можно сделать через `outline`, но я не нахожу у него свойства `radius` + я не хочу играться с позициями блоков через `absolute` либо `relative`, хотелось бы простое решение. Подскажите пож-та как можно обыграть данную ситуацию без `outline`, но так чтобы блоки не смещались из-за толщины `border`.

Для наглядности, создал пример

```
http://jsfiddle.net/s1p2Ly88/3/
```

Нужно нажать на любой блок и отжать, тогда все уведите. Спс за ранее;-)

Comment: С соледар согласен но и так же можно добавить box-sizing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

добавь  `border: 4px solid transparent;` для `.box > .items`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(".items").on("click", function()
 {   
  if( $(this).hasClass('box-checked') ){
   $(this).removeClass('box-checked')
  }else{
   $(".box").find('.box-checked').each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('box-checked');
            })
            $(this).addClass('box-checked')
  }
 });

    $('.colors').each(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', getRandomColor)       
        
    })
    
    function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }
})
```

```css
.box{    
    cursor: pointer;
}
.box > .items{          
    border-radius: 3px;
    color:#ffffff;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 4px solid transparent;    
}
.box > .box-checked{
    border:4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <div class="items colors">
        box1    
    </div>
    <div class="items colors">
        box2       
    </div>
    <div class="items colors">
        box3
    </div>
    <div class="items colors">
        box4
    </div>
</div>
```

Второй вариант - вместо `border` использовать `box-shadow`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(".items").on("click", function()
 {   
  if( $(this).hasClass('box-checked') ){
   $(this).removeClass('box-checked')
  }else{
   $(".box").find('.box-checked').each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('box-checked');
            })
            $(this).addClass('box-checked')
  }
 });

    $('.colors').each(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', getRandomColor)       
        
    })
    
    function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }
})
```

```css
.box{    
    cursor: pointer;    
}
.box > .items{          
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color:#ffffff;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 5px;    
}
.box-checked{
    background-clip: border-box;
}
.box > .box-checked{    
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <div class="items colors">
        box1    
    </div>
    <div class="items colors">
        box2       
    </div>
    <div class="items colors">
        box3
    </div>
    <div class="items colors">
        box4
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/prkc5frh/)

Comment: Супер!!! Все просто, не знал про свойство transparent. Спасибо за быстрый ответ)